# Effective transform OHE to sparse

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

After OHE my data looks like this:

```
client|feat1|feat2
     1|    1|    0
     3|    0|    1
     5|    1|    0
```

I want to add this information about client/features to to my `sparse df`. I cant simply call sparse constructor here since indexes (client ids) matter. Constructor will return sparse matrix 3x3 whereas in reality I have at least 6 rows (max id in this toy example is 5) in my `sparse df`. I know how to create and add features one by one, i.e. each time create sparse matrix of size (*number of clients in `sparse df` x 1*) for each feature and stack this information to `sparse df`.

So, my question is:

Is there any effective way to utilize (add to `sparse df`) all OHE info about some clients at once with respect to clients id?

Comment: `sparse df`?  What is this? You have a `scipy` tag.  But `df` usually is a `pandas` dataframe (which does have a `sparse` feature.)

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#sparse-matrix-classes any of sparse matrixes from here. csr, coo, etc.

Comment: The data, row, col arrays specified by the coo format are the best constructor.

Comment: Well, thank you, but that's not what I've asked about. I know how to solve my question on column by column basis and I'm asking whether it's possible to call constructor here on all columns at once? `sparse.csr_matrix((feat1, (df['client'], [0]*df['client']))` will give me vector presenting one feature. I want to process all features at one time, if it's possible. (since I know that client either have feat1 XOR feat2)